# Prove or disprove that there exists a linear map given a set of vectors and their mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

I'm stuck on this seemingly simple homework question, but I just don't know how to approach it at all :( Here is the question:

"  Prove or disprove that there is a Linear map $T:\mathbb{R^{3}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^{3}}}$ such that the following occurs:

$T\left(2,1,1\right)=\left(0,3,1\right)$

$T\left(0,3,6\right)=\left(9,2,3\right)$

$T\left(1,2,5\right)=\left(7,3,2\right)$
"

OK I have absolutely no idea how to approach this question. I suppose there is a more elegant way than to sit around and do a trial & error approach to find out the equation for the Linear Map.

Any hints on how to solve it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, you can check to see whether the vectors $(2,1,1), (0,3,6), (1,2,5)$ are linearly-independent. If they are, then they form a basis for $\mathbb R^3$ . And if they are a basis, knowing the action on them ( meaning their image under $T$ ), defines $T$ fully, and uniquely. And then the matrix representation of $T$ is given by the columns $T(a,b,c)$.

Comment: Oh I understand now, but I don't quite understand the T(a,b,c) part. I know that if I know how a linear transformation works on the basis of a Vector space then that transformation is unique. But if the vectors that are given to me are linearly dependent meaning they do not form a basis, is that enough to disprove that such a linear map exists?

Comment: That's a good question; let me think it thru. Actually, there are results to the effect that linear maps defined on subspaces may be extended into linear maps defined on the whole space. Let me try to remember them.